# Question about Reduction of an Asymptotic Equation

Tags: summation, asymptotics

I was wondering if someone could explain what is happening between the last couple steps in this problem. I think it has something to do with the asymptotic notation? I have written a question mark in the photo to indicate the part I am confused about. Thank you very much

[question_photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m5SaJ.png)

Comment: You may also want to try the Computer Science StackExchange in the future, at http://cs.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Math StackExchange!

You can find help formatting your math [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/2626).

For the step

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\sum_{k=1}^{n-i}{ \frac{2}{k+1} } \tag{1}$$
$$< \sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\sum_{k=1}^{n}{ \frac{2}{k} } \tag{2}$$

note that $k$ goes from $1$ to $n$ in Equation (2), while in Equation (1), it goes from $1$ to $n-i$.  Since $n-i$ is at most $n-1$, which happens when $i=1$, the sum of $\frac{2}{k+1}$ is added a smaller number of times.
Also

$$\frac{2}{k+1} < \frac{2}{k} \tag{3}$$